# Warning: require_once(includes/EliteScript.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in

Tags: php, fatal-error

This is a licence based script and it has a valid licence using SourceGuardian. The script was working fine on client's old server and he hired me to migrate it to the new server.

After migrating, everything was working fine but not the login area, when trying to login it gives the follow error

```
Warning: require_once(includes/EliteScript.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/sitetalk/public_html/interface/index.php on line 3

Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required 'includes/EliteScript.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/sitetalk/public_html/interface/index.php on line 3
```

Registration works fine and can see the filled data in database. Tried to take it to the script developer, but there's no response since 3months.

Not sure, what causing this error to happen. Pasting the part of code of the shown file names.

```
EliteScript.php

    <?php
global $config;
global $country_array;
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE ^ E_WARNING ^ E_DEPRECATED);
define("ES_VERSION", "7.0.4");
define("ES_SERVER", "http://primary.shadowscripts.com/master/server.php");
define("ES_FLASH", "/includes/graphs/src/lang/my.inc.php");
define("ES_VERIFYDEV", "eth0");
require_once("ShadowScripts.php");
require_once("interface/template.php");
spl_autoload_register(function($class)
    {
    if ($class == "EliteScriptBase")
        {
        return 0;
        }
    if ($class != "FusionCharts_Gen.php")
        {
        $class = preg_replace("/\\_/", "/", $class);
        }
    $class       = preg_replace("/\\\\/", "/", $class);
   ?>
```

and

```
index.php

<?php 
global $es;
global $ui;
global $member_id;
global $base_url;
global $member_url;
global $image_url;
global $admin_url;
require_once("includes/EliteScript.php");
$es = new EliteScript();
$ui = new UserInterface();
$es->RequireMember();
$member_id = $es->GetMemberId();
$base_url = $es->GetConfig("baseUrl");
$member_url = $es->GetConfig("memberUrl");
$image_url = $es->GetConfig("imageUrl");
$f_login_page = $es->GetLoginUIPage();
if( $f_login_page ) 
{
    $ui->ChangePage($f_login_page);
}

$es->DisplayHeader($es->getText("home_window_title"), "member.php");
switch( $_REQUEST["do"] ) 
{
    case "toggle_autorenew":
        toggle_autorenew();
        break;
    default:
        display_main();
}
$es->DisplayFooter();
echo "\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n";
function toggle_autorenew()
{
    global $es;
    global $ui;
    global $member_id;
    global $base_url;
    global $member_url;
    global $image_url;
    global $admin_url;
    $way = $_REQUEST["way"];
    $es->ToggleMembershipAutoRenew($member_id, $way);
    $ui->SetMessage("msg", $es->getText("home_togglerenew_success"));
    $ui->ChangePage($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);
}

function display_main()
?>
```

As it says on line 3, I find nothing to edit. Please help what I can do to fix this.

Thanks

Comment: check your include directory file are there?

Comment: EliteScript.php file directory path?

Comment: public_html/includes/EliteScript.php

Comment: If you moved the files and folders as they were and it's a new server, consider to check your `require_path` in your php.ini file.

Comment: Ok bro, let me check.

Comment: index.php file directory path?

Comment: @QaisarSatti public_html/interface/index.php

Comment: @OfirBaruch can't find any php.ini file in the cpanel, but when I've created a new file for phpinfo();, it showed this Configuration File (php.ini) Path /usr/lib
Loaded Configuration File /usr/local/lib/php.ini

But I can't find the location of the file.

Comment: You are attempting to include the EliteScript file from public_html/interface/includes/EliteScript.pho but the file is located one directory up. So you changed directory structure while uploading.

Comment: @Luceos no idea how it happend bro, I havn't changed anything, but now I have the idea where this error coming from. 

The script is actually encoded with sourceguardian, need to decode it.

Tried to copy the includes/EliteScript.php to interface folder, but it was asking for more and more files and it's a big mess, so I'll ask my client to get one file decoded.

So, Can you please advice me which file I should edit? just the includes/EliteScript.php or interface/index.php?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this  and check it is working or not

```
require_once("includes/EliteScript.php");
```

to

```
require_once("../includes/EliteScript.php");
```

**Explanation**
  current code calling current `directory/includes/EliteScript.php` but your file in previous directory so you have to add `../` it will include file from  previous directory.

Comment: An explanation would be helpful. What was the problem and how did you solve it?

Answer (score 2):

The problem you encounter has to do with relative and absolute paths in the `include` and `require` functions of php. Your index file is requiring the `EliteScript.php` with a relative path.

Articles about the difference between relative and absolute:

- [php relative and absolute paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1755216/php-relative-and-absolute-paths)
- [PHP: Absolute vs. relative paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8356547/php-absolute-vs-relative-paths)
- And a comparison table: http://www.geeksengine.com/article/absolute-relative-path.html

In your comments you mention the files are encrypted, so the best way to handle this is to keep the directory structure in exact the same way as the files are given to you.

The specifically point out (as I've done in the comments) where the problem lies:

`public_html/interface/index.php` loads the relative path `includes/EliteScript.php` which therefor will require the path `public_html/interface/includes/EliteScript.php` however your EliteScript.php is located in `public_html/includes/EliteScript.php`.

Comment: I have tried to copy the files to where it is actually expecting, but it's asking for more files and tried to all I can. there are alot of files and it was hard to change anymore locations when it end up at /home/sitetalk/public_html/interface/includes/../config.inc.php

How to make it to follow relative path then? I can get 1 file decoded, which one should I?

The server it was migrated to now is from the same ISP, I havn't changed any file's location, I have migrated it as it is.

Comment: You don't change the code otherwise you break stuff. Try to get back to the directory structure it was meant to be and if it needs more files then you probably f**ked up :P Sorry to say. Try uploading from scratch and don't change directory structure (again).

Comment: No, I havn't changed the directory structure in any form bro.

I have just compressed the files and folders on old server and extracted in new one.

It always works fine until it's changed to new server, and developer needs to fix it, but he's not active since last 3 months. That is why I'm here. :(

Answer (score 0):

The other answers maybe true, but they didn't fix my problem.

I did exactly as it was showing in [this article](http://www.geeksengine.com/article/php-include-path.html)

I edited the include_path in php.ini and it's working like charm.