# How to check if these php modules like mod_php5.c are installed on my server?

Tags: php, module

How do I check if mod_php5.c, mod_suphp.c and mod_rewrite.c are installed on my server?

Tried searching there before posting here, but I can't find any with these names, does that mean they're not installed? Or if it's installed, where does it show in the phpinfo()?

I'm using WHM/CPANEL, Cent OS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

create a file with name like info.php and write the below code in it and execute and see all the php information in it.

```
    <?php
      phpinfo();
    ?>
```

Comment: Tried searching there before posting here, but I can't find any with these names, does that mean they're not installed? Or if it's installed, where does it show in the phpinfo()?

Comment: @Steve, yes they are not installed if your `phpinfo()`  function does not show them.

Comment: Ok thank you so much mate, I have posted few other questions. About the paths, which was working fine on other server but doesn't on the new server. Here --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30206147/warning-require-onceincludes-elitescript-php-function-require-once-failed

So this wasn't working on server as these modules were not installed on this server.

Comment: This is what's written on .htaccess

<IfModule mod_php5.c>
php_value include_path ".:/home/revsurfprofit/public_html"

Answer (score 2):

You can use `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` to check php list of active php modules.

[image: active php modules in phpinfo via chrome]

Comment: Tried searching there before posting here, but I can't find any with these names, does that mean they're not installed? Or if it's installed, where does it show in the phpinfo()?

Comment: There is no "apache2handler" or "Loaded Modules" in mine, what do I do?  It's a linux dedicated server.