# How do you confirm if .htaccess if working fine?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, whm

I have this htaccess, I'm not sure if these modules mod_php5.c , mod_suphp.c and mod_rewrite.c are working or not. How do I check if they're working and doing their job?

Tried checking if the mod_php5.c , mod_suphp.c and mod_rewrite.c are installed, but they were not showing in `phpinfo();`

I'm using Linux server, have WHM/cPanel, CentOS.

```
# PHP Flags
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
php_value include_path ".:/home/sitetalk/public_html"
php_flag display_errors off
php_flag magic_quotes_gpc off
php_value default_charset "utf-8"
php_value error_log "/home/sitetalk/public_html/../application_error_log"
</IfModule>

# If using suPHP set a custom INI path
<IfModule mod_suphp.c>
suPHP_ConfigPath /home/sitetalk/public_html
</IfModule>

# Rewrites
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

# Block all non-hostname attempts
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?sitetalk.com$
RewriteRule . - [F]

# friendly banner codes
RewriteRule ^banners/([0-9]+)\.gif$ /interface/display_banner.php?do=display&id=$1
RewriteRule ^banners/rotator/([0-9]+)\.gif$ /interface/display_banner_rotator.php?do=image&id=$1
RewriteRule ^banners/rotator/click/([0-9]+)$ /interface/display_banner_rotator.php?do=click&id=$1
RewriteRule ^banners/affiliates/([0-9]+)\.gif$ /interface/display_affiliate.php?do=image&id=$1
RewriteRule ^banners/([0-9]+)/click$ /interface/bannerads_click.php?id=$1
RewriteRule ^banners/ppc/([0-9]+)/click$ /interface/ppc_click.php?id=$1
RewriteRule ^banners/offsite/([0-9A-Z]+)$ /interface/offsiteadzonehandler.php?id=$1
RewriteRule ^banners/offsite/([0-9A-Z]+)/click/([0-9A-Z]+)$ /interface/offsiteadzonehandler.php?do=click&id=$1&cid=$2

# HTTPS to HTTP on viewads page
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/interface/viewads.php [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/interface/viewads_ptc.php
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.revsurfprofit.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L,QSA]

#RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/interface/viewads.php
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/interface/viewads_ptc.php
#RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L,QSA]

# Referral code
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)(|/)$ index.php?ref=$1  [L]
</IfModule>

# Deny files
<files php.ini>
order deny,allow
deny from all
</files>
```

Comment: What kind of issue are you facing?

Comment: This --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30206147/warning-require-onceincludes-elitescript-php-function-require-once-failed

Comment: I'm assuming if the modules are working, this issue will get fixed.

Comment: See this article : https://helponnet.com/2021/05/14/know-wether-htaccess-is-working-on-apache/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apache modules are not shown in phpinfo().
You can run `httpd -M` command to see, which modules have loaded.

Also you can set a special http-header inside each .htaccess section to check if it works.
Example:

```
<IfModule mod_suphp.c>
Header set X-SuPHP-Works 1
</IfModule>
```

And see the response headers.