# How to create a proper php include statement that works on all folder levels

Tags: php

Looking for php include statement that works regardless on how nested the folders are. I use

```
../includes/file.php
```

and that works for only one level folder. If I re-use that code at different folder levels it does not work. If I add the complete path

```
/account/website/protected/includes/file.php
```

it does not work. If I add a partial path

```
/protected/includes/file.php
```

it does not work. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If you use an absolute path, you need to use the root of your host machine, not of your project. Which is also a very bad practice!

Comment: @Jerodev Can you explain in short why absolute path are bad practice? Only one point given: `You have defined an constant with the base path to your project home`. `include BASE_PATH.'path/to/file.php'`

Comment: Read here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8356547/php-absolute-vs-relative-paths

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1755216/php-relative-and-absolute-paths  look for `include(dirname(__FILE__)."/includes/myscript.php");`